# How to gray out an NSMenuItem?

Tags: swift, macos, menu, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I'm writing an app with Swift targeted to macOS Sierra.

I have an NSMenuItem that I'd like to gray out (so the user can't even select it).

I have set its parent menu AutoEnableItems to FALSE in the Storyboard and verified that it's still false via logging in my code.

When I set the isEnabled property of my NSMenuItem to false, what it does is that my action associated with the menu item isn't called (which is good) when I select that menu item, but the menu remains selectable.

What I'd like is for it to be grayed out, and obviously not selectable by the user.

Comment: You want to make it grayed out.  From where?  A view controller?  A window controller?  AppDelegate?  A singleton?

Comment: @ElTomato - it's from my AppDelegate, in the context of a notification callback (an observer to the NotificationCenter): I want the menu to get enabled/disabled based on new values that triggered the notification

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for.  Who is posting the notification and how?

Comment: @ElTomato Component A calls NotificationCenter.default.post() in response to one of its properties (a boolean) changing. This is done in the didSet() function attached to that property. My AppDelegate is an observer for that notification and its callback is called. In the callback I check the value of a boolean and set the MenuItem according to its value: if true, I want the menu Enabled and Black (therefore selectable), and if false, I want the menu Disabled and Grayed Out (not selectable)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, what you're doing does sound correct.

However, the way I do it is to implement `validateMenuItem` in my AppDelegate class. This method is a little bit annoying because it gets called for every menu item, with the menu item being passed as a parameter. So you have to switch on the parameter, see if it's the menu item you want to disable, and return false.

There's an Objective-C example here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1518160-validatemenuitem

A Swift example might look like:

```
override func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {       
    switch menuItem.tag {
    case MenuItemTags.SignOut:
        return signOutEnabled()
    case MenuItemTags.CheckForUpdates:
        return updatesEnabled()
    default:
        return true
    }
}
```

You may have read this already, but lots of gory details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html

However, as I said, this article would seem to indicate what you're trying is correct, so who knows? I can say for sure my way works.