# How can I update isEnabled of an NSMenuItem in Cocoa Swift macOS?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I searched in older questions about updating isEnabled of a NSMenuItem and i reached to this codes:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private var myArray: Array<Int> = Array(0...2)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let item0: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "add an Item", action: #selector(actionOfItem0), keyEquivalent: "a")
        item0.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        let item1: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "remove an Item", action: #selector(actionOfItem1), keyEquivalent: "r")
        item1.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command

     
        let menu: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        menu.submenu = NSMenu()
        menu.submenu?.items = [item0, item1]

        let mainMenu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        mainMenu.items = [menu]
        NSApplication.shared.mainMenu = mainMenu

    }

    @objc func actionOfItem0() {

        if (myArray.count <= 5) {
            myArray.append(myArray.count)
            print(myArray)
            
            NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.item(at: 0)?.submenu?.item(at: 1)?.isEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.item(at: 0)?.submenu?.item(at: 0)?.isEnabled = false
            
            print(NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.item(at: 0)?.submenu?.item(at: 0)?.title)
        }

    }

    @objc func actionOfItem1() {
        
        if (!myArray.isEmpty) {
            myArray.removeLast()
            print(myArray)
            
            NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.item(at: 0)?.submenu?.item(at: 0)?.isEnabled = true
        }
        else {

            NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.items[0].submenu?.items[1].isEnabled = false
            NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.item(at: 0)?.submenu?.item(at: 1)?.isEnabled = false
            
            print(NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.item(at: 0)?.submenu?.item(at: 1)?.title)
            
        }

    }
    
}
```

I am enable to update NSApplication.shared about the correct value but the NSMenuItem itself does not get updated, for example I can set `false` for `NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.item(at: 0)?.submenu?.item(at: 1)?.isEnabled = false` but the item itself is not get updated! How to solve the issue?

Comment: Just modifying `isEnabled` doesn't work, you have to implement the delegate method [validateMenuItem(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitemvalidation/3005191-validatemenuitem)

Comment: Or switch off `autoenablesItems` of the menu.

Comment: @vadian: So do I need `isEnabled` and `validateMenuItem(_:)` and delegate all 3 in same time? Can you show a sample code?

Comment: The linked documentation contains an example. You have to check each affected menu item for a given condition and return `true` to enable the item otherwise `false`. Don't forget to set the delegate of the menu to the class which adopts the protocol..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to gray out an NSMenuItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005253/how-to-gray-out-an-nsmenuitem)

Comment: @Willeke: I really got confused, which thing is controlling NSMenuItem, autoenablesItems or isEnabled?

Comment: Which part of the documentation is confusing?

Comment: @vadian is `validateMenuItem(_:)` implemented by the delegate or the target?

Comment: @Willeke `validateMenuItem` is a delegate method of the `NSMenuItemValidation` protocol

Comment: @vadian the delegate of `NSMenu` is a `id<NSMenuDelegate>`.

Comment: @Willeke Sorry, my bad, it's indeed related to the target. Adopt the protocol and implement the required method.